# Line across the entire screen that occurs only when running Xfce with a Dock application

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, cairo-dock

I have noticed that whenever I use Xfce with a Dock application running (including Cairo Dock or Docky) I see a horizontal line across my entire screen about 5/6th the way down the screen. This glitch does **not** occur under any other DE, including:

- GNOME
- KDE
- LXDE
- MATE

See this screenshot to see this horizontal line, the Dock application running in this screenshot is, as you can probably guess by the opened configuration window, Cairo Dock. My OS is Arch Linux, I will be happy to provide any further information you want. [Here](http://paste2.org/6ZtIz2XU) is my `lspci -k` output if you think it might have something to do with my graphics card. I suspect this may be a bug in Xfce, but I was not comfortable reporting it until I am sure it is a bug in Xfce and not an Arch Linux bug or something I have made a mistake with.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uncheck Settings Manager > Window Manager Tweaks > Compositor > Show shadows under dock windows.